# Accessing a UITextField in a custom UITableViewCell without creating a new class?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, class, uitextfield

So I know that you could reference a `UITextField` that you created in the interface builder by creating a custom `UITableViewCell` class and connect it with an `IBOutlet`.

But is this good code practice? I mean I am basically just creating a new class for a `UITextField`. Is there a more suitable way to do this? AFAIK you can't set an `IBOutlet` to the `UITableViewController` itself since you can't reference objects on repeating content.

Comment: Do you have a `UITableViewController` or a `UIViewcontroller` with a tableView inside of it? What does your code look like?

Comment: I have a UITableViewController with a tableView inside of it. I created two prototype cells. The first cell is for displaying a dynamic content and the second cell is inside another tableView section. Inside of the second cell I have a TextField that I'd like to reference inside of the UITableViewController

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is a good practise. When I first started learning swift, I myself went through this phase because creating a new class overtime seemed a lot of work. But trust me, it is the best way. I learned swift from a book which I bought from AppCoda. It always emphasises on creating custom classes for tableView cells as well as CollectionView cells.

In your example you have 2 prototype cells, creating custom classes for both of them helps in differencing one cel from the other. Also, you will also not get confused between the two. This also helps in changing settings/appearance of cells as you like and with ease.

Hope this helps. :)